# FileList not showing size in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, dojo

I have an Uploader and connected to it a FileList as the documentation recommends. And it is working as expected in Firefox, Chrome.
BUT in IE9 there is one User Interface issue. When the tab in which it exists gets created the FileList does not show the size column.

Is it a known issue? Should it behave like that? To be more specific when the FileList first gets shown in the IE I see a flickr of the 'size' column and then it disappears...

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support [XMLHttpRequest2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) and therefore `Uploader` cannot obtain file sizes of selected files and for this case there is code hiding the column in `dojox/form/uploader/FileList.js`:

```
if(!(this._fileSizeAvail = {'html5':1,'flash':1}[this.uploader.uploadType])){
    //if uploadType is neither html5 nor flash, file size is not available
    //hide the size header
    this.sizeHeader.style.display="none";
}
```

So, the answer is yes, it should behave like that, unless you use `dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash` plugin in IE.